# SSL Issues with Java PKIX / validator.ValidatorException despite proxy

Tags: java, https, jvm, http-proxy

We're in a scenario where a corporate proxy is decrypting all HTTPS traffic and re-signing it with a CA ROOT which Java does not trust.

We're also in a scenario where we are unable to modify the cacerts file in the Java directory.

We're getting the following issue in many Java applications:

```
sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: 
sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find 
valid certification path to requested target
```

We don't want to have to add individual certificates.

What we can do is change JVM arguments however:

1. `-Dtrust_all_cert=true` has no effect
2. `-Dhttps.proxyHost=localhost -Dhttps.proxyPort=8888` has no effect

With step 2 we are trying to go through Fiddler as a proxy but no requests appear when we do HTTPS requests.

If we set `-Dhttp.proxyHost=localhost -Dhttp.proxyPort=8888` and do HTTP requests we see the traffic in Fiddler. So...

1. Why doesn't trust_all_cert help here?
2. Why doesn't Java use the https proxy we specify?

NB: We've even tried making a java program hardwired to use localhost:8888 as a proxy. Again, works for HTTP but not HTTPS.

Answer (score 0):

One way is to make a new cacerts file and use that in the JVM:

1. Download the CA Root certificate (e.g. root.cer)
2. `keytool -import -noprompt -trustcacerts -alias root -file root.cer -keystore .\cacertsnew -storepass ***`
3. `java -Dhttps.proxyHost=someproxy -Dhttps.proxyPort=8080 -Djavax.net.ssl.trustStore=cacertsnew ...`

Comment: Unfortunately does not help with gradlew.